# FOREIGN KEY constraint exception

Tags: sql, entity-framework-5

I have a one to many relation between two tables (A user can have multiple albums) and albums table also have some relations with other tables.
The problem is when I want to save an album a FOREIGN KEY constraint exception will occur but the user exists and the foreign key is specified.

Here's the exception:

> *The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Albums_CreatedBy".
>
>   The conflict occurred in database "{Database Name}", table "dbo.Users", column 'Id'.
>
>   The statement has been terminated.*

this is the mapping code of the album and user in the constructor of the album class:

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.CreatedBy)
            .WithMany(t => t.Albums)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.CreatedById);
```

this is the save code:

```
private void InsertAlbum(MyContext context, Album album)
{
    album.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    album.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    album.CreatedBy = context.Users.Single(u => u.UserName == "SomeUser"); // User exists and has Id = 1
    album.RowVersion = Guid.NewGuid();

    // Assigning other relations...

    context.Albums.Add(album);
    context.SaveChanges(); // This is the place that the exception occurs.
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've find out the error is acctualy wrong because the Albums table has another one to many relation with Metadatas table and if I not insert any metadata with a album I will not receive any exceptions.
Now I'm not sure what will cause the error and why it shows me an incorrect error.

Comment: can you post the code for the entity and the configuration class?

Comment: I would fire up a profiler on the database to see what SQL statements are actually getting executed.

Comment: Which profiler do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting `CreatedBy` to the user *name*, not the user *id*.  Try something like this:

```
album.CreatedBy = context.Users.Single(u.id)
```

(Sorry, I don't know the right syntax here, but the concept should be right)

Comment: This isn't the case because the context.Users.Single(u => u.UserName == "SomeUser"); will return an instance of User. UserName is unique in my database.